# How to get the containing class of a field symbol with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, field, roslyn

I'm trying to get the containing class of a field using roslyn. I see that I can get the containing namespace using `myfield.ContainingNamespace;`, so it must be a way to get the class.

I think it will be easy if I can split the field's symbol using `myfield.Split('.');` and get the class. But I'm looking for a proper way to do it (Like getting the namespace).

So how I can get the containing class from the field's symbol (without using the **semantic model** will be great)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is myField? If it's `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol` than there is `ContainingType`

[ISymbol](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ISymbol.cs,c8ad9ffeacf174ca,references)

Comment: Yes that's what i need, myField is the field's symbol (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol), thanks